# Description div overlay not showing on li image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slideshow

I am using the slider http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/ and am trying to add description boxes that overlay the images and change with each div. I added a div class, but it is not showing up. Not sure if I also need to alter javascript?

css

```
.blueberry { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width:1280px; 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:1;  
    margin-top:-25px; 

}

.blueberry .slides {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;

}
.blueberry .slides li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.blueberry .slides li img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;

}
.blueberry .slides li.active { display: block; position: relative; }
.blueberry .crop li img { width: auto; }

.slides .description {
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    background:#000;
    color:#1d1d1d;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blueberry shadow">
  <ul class="slides"> 
  <li><img src="images/slide1.jpg" />
  <div class="description">
  <p>Kick off 2013 by starting a fundraising campaign to help people get access to clean water. It&rsquo;s fun, it&rsquo;s easy and it&rsquo;s the best way we can think to start the new year.</p></div></li>
```

js

```
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
$('.blueberry').blueberry();
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define css `top` property, see it works fine:

[image]

Note: Using `div` or `p` inside `ul li` is agaisnt to the web standarts. I suggest to use tags like `span`, `em`, `s`, `i`.